# Adding Permalink attribution to the leaflet map in order to reach another URL permalink

Tags: leaflet, javascript

Continuing the issue opened here:

[Link to another URL permalink in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339126/link-to-another-url-permalink-in-leaflet)

I found some code, that may help me to establish a link to another url permalink from the leaflet map:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MapBBCode/mapbbcode/master/src/controls/PermalinkAttribution.js

The library is the "PermalinkAttribution". 
Inside this file important is:

```
 for (var i in this._attributions) {
        if (this._attributions[i]) {
            // make permalink for openstreetmap
            if( i.indexOf('/openstreetmap.org') > 0 || 
 i.indexOf('/www.openstreetmap.org') > 0 ) {
                var permalink = 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map= 
 {zoom}/{lat}/{lon}';
                i = i.replace(/(['"])http[^'"]+openstreetmap.org[^'"]* 
  (['"])/, '$1' + permalink + '$2');
                if( this._map.options.attributionEditLink ) {
                    var editlink = permalink.replace('#', 'edit#');
                    i = i.replace(/(openstreetmap.org[^'"]*(['"])[^>]*>[^<]+ 
  <\/a>)/, '$1 (<a href=$2' + editlink + '$2 target=$2osmedit$2>Edit</a>)');
                }
            }
            var latlng = this._map.getCenter();
            i = i.replace(/\{zoom\}/g, this._map.getZoom()).replace(/\ 
  {lat\}/g, L.Util.formatNum(latlng.lat, 4)).replace(/\{lon\}/g, 
  L.Util.formatNum(latlng.lng, 4));
            attribs.push(i);
        }
    }
```

but so far major problem for me was how to add it on the map.

I tried:

```
   L.Control.Attribution.extend({}).addTo(map);

   L.Control.PermalinkAttribution{}).addTo(map);
```

but nothing works.

Console says:

throw new Error('Map container not found.');

and I have no button on  my map shown.

Does anyone knows how to attach the permalink attribution to the leaflet map?